# When is the best time to buy airline tickets?

Tags: purchase, airline

How long before a flight is the best time to get the lowest fares?

Do prices on fare-finding sites change depending on the time of day or day of week?  When is best?

Comment: Why the votes to close (as off-topic)? It seems like a money-saving question.

Comment: Questions of the variety " **where can I find the lowest price on** ..." were voted as off-topic at the area51 proposal.  This is very similar in nature.  To discuss more where the line ought to be drawn, we can head to http://meta.money.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's not exactly a "where can I find the lowest price on..." question - it's asking for recommendations based on the historical fluctuations of a relatively closed industry.  It's similar to  a question like, "When is the best time to refinance?"

Comment: Meta-discussion over here: http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/48/general-advice-on-getting-good-prices

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://abcnews.go.com/print?id=4519704) seems to have good information:

- Buy early, but not too early
- Don't necessarily wait until the last minute
- Sales tend to happen at the beginning of the week
- Technology is your friend